Issues with PyDictionary
I imported the PyDictionary library for a project I was beginning in Python, but no matter what word I use, the meaning function returns an empty dict. Here is my script so far:
# Import Libraries
from tkinter import *
from gtts import gTTS
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
import random

# Create Functions
def chooserandom(list: list):
    return list[random.randrange(0, len(list))]

# Create Variables
words: list[str] = "".join(list(open("word-lists\\mainlist.txt", "r"))).split("\n")
dictionary = PyDictionary()

# Main Loop
word: str = chooserandom(words)
definition = dictionary.meaning(word)
print(word) # amber
print(definition) # {}

"word-lists\\mainlist.txt" is a txt file of English words.
print(word) works properly and prints a random word (as a string) from the file (e.g. "amber").
print(definition) always prints {}.
Any help or advice is greatly appreciated!

Are you aware that PyDictionary has not been updated in almost 4 years? Based on the note added over a year ago in the README on GitHub, I would be quite shocked if it still worked.

I did not know that. Are there any other working dictionary libraries that you know of?

I don’t personally have any recommendations, no.

chooserandom is a curious thing to implement given that random.choice exists.

@Chris thank you for telling me. I had no idea that was a thing!

The question isn't about reading a file and choosing a word from it, so we don't need to see that code.  Just assign word = "amber" directly.  It makes the question clearer and shorter.

@JohnGordon sorry, I'm new to posting on here. Thank you for your advice!

Thanks to esqew for informing me that PyDictionary probably no longer works.
I found another library that does work; here is the new code:
# Import Libraries
from tkinter import *
from gtts import gTTS
from freedictionaryapi.clients.sync_client import DictionaryApiClient
import random

# Create Functions
def getdefinitions(word: str):
    with DictionaryApiClient() as client:
        parser = client.fetch_parser(word)
    definitions: dict[str:str] = {}
    for pair in parser.meanings:
        definitions[pair.part_of_speech] = pair.definitions[0].definition
    return definitions

# Create Variables
words: list[str] = "".join(list(open("word-lists\\mainlist.txt", "r"))).split("\n")

# Main Loop
word: str = random.choice(words)
definitions: dict[str:str] = getdefinitions(word)
print(word) # amber
print(definitions) # {'noun': 'Ambergris, the waxy product of the sperm whale.', 'verb': 'To perfume or flavour with ambergris.', 'adjective': 'Of a brownish yellow colour, like that of most amber.'}

Just make sure you have run both commands (Windows):
pip install python-freeDictionaryAPI
pip install httpx

Thanks for the help!
